# How to get the contents of python object <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> as a string when using PIPE of subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, subprocess

I have a problem. My subprocess module is spitting out something that I do not know how to deal with.

Using Python 3 on Arch Linux.

Command includes:

- `svn info`
- `grep -IEi`
- `sed -e`

Despite my terminal ouput of `3` for the revision number, I cannot seem to get this value stored into a Python variable. It has something to do with my getting an object instead of the contents of that object I suspect. Any help would be appreciated.

For completeness, I demonstrate how the parameter `universal_lines` can influence the output.

Given that the svn revision on my system is `3`:

### With `shell=True, cwd=branch, universal_lines=False`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

branch = '/home/username/svncheckoutfolder'
command = 'svn info "%s" | grep -IEi "Revision:" | sed -e "s/^Revision: \\([0-9]*\\)/\\1/g"' % (branch) # filters out revision number from svn info command
process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,cwd=branch) # cwd=branch is only necessary when command contains LaTeX interpreter. In this case, I included the absolute path within the command.
process_stdout = process.communicate()[0]
current_revision = process.stdout # This should be a revision number.
print (type(current_revision)) # <class '_io.BufferedReader'>
print (current_revision) # <_io.BufferedReader name=3>
```

#### Result:

```
<class '_io.BufferedReader'>
<_io.BufferedReader name=3>
```

### With `shell=True, cwd=branch, universal_lines=True`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

branch = '/home/username/svncheckoutfolder'
command = 'svn info "%s" | grep -IEi "Revision:" | sed -e "s/^Revision: \\([0-9]*\\)/\\1/g"' % (branch) # filters out revision number from svn info command
process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,cwd=branch) # cwd=branch is only necessary when command contains LaTeX interpreter. In this case, I included the absolute path within the command.
process_stdout = process.communicate()[0]
current_revision = process.stdout # This should be a revision number.
print (type(current_revision)) # <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
print (current_revision) # <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='UTF-8'>
```

#### Result:

```
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I tried reading the object, but that does not work either:

```
print(current_revision.read())
```

#### Result:

```
ValueError: read of closed file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the return value of `Popen.communicate()` here:

```
current_revision = process.stdout
```

You are referencing the (now closed) file object the `subprocess` module used to communicate with the shell. You are ignoring the value returned on the previous line altogether.

Just use:

```
process_stdout = process.communicate()[0]
current_revision = process_stdout.decode('utf8').strip()
```

when not using `universal_newlines=True`, or

```
process_stdout = process.communicate()[0]
current_revision = process_stdout.strip()
```

when you do. The data includes a newline, hence the `str.strip()` call.

You could just use the [`subprocess.check_output()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), if all you need is the stdout output of the command:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    command, shell=True, cwd=branch, universal_newlines=True)
```

Last but not least, it may be simpler to have *Python* do the parsing of the response:

```
command = ('svn', 'info', branch)
output = subprocess.check_output(command, universal_newlines=True)
revision = None
for line in output.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('Revision:'):
        revision = line.partition(':')[1].strip()
        break
```